# Case statement not working with or condition

Tags: mysql

Please help me with this code.

```
 SELECT (CASE LEFT(BRANCH_CODE, 1)
        WHEN '1' THEN 'NL'
        WHEN '2' THEN 'MM'
        WHEN '3' THEN 'SL'
        WHEN '4' THEN 'VIS'
        WHEN '5' THEN 'MIN'
        WHEN ('7' OR '8') THEN 'SA'
         END)  `REGION`,
```

This is the result:

```
Region
null
MM
```

The result should be like this:

```
Region
SA
MM
```

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax is not valid:

```
WHEN ('7' OR '8') THEN 'SA'
```

What follows `WHEN` or `ELSE` using this style of `CASE` expression can only be a literal value, not a logical expression.  So, you could refactor to:

```
SELECT
    CASE LEFT(BRANCH_CODE, 1)
        WHEN '1' THEN 'NL'
        WHEN '2' THEN 'MM'
        WHEN '3' THEN 'SL'
        WHEN '4' THEN 'VIS'
        WHEN '5' THEN 'MIN'
        WHEN '7' THEN 'SA'                -- repeat the 'SA' predicate twice
        WHEN '8' THEN 'SA' END AS REGION
FROM yourTable;
```

If you wanted to combine the `7` and `8` cases in a single `WHEN`, then you would have to use the longer form of `CASE`:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN LEFT(BRANCH_CODE, 1) = '1' THEN 'NL'
         WHEN LEFT(BRANCH_CODE, 1) = '2' THEN 'MM'
         WHEN LEFT(BRANCH_CODE, 1) = '3' THEN 'SL'
         WHEN LEFT(BRANCH_CODE, 1) = '4' THEN 'VIS'
         WHEN LEFT(BRANCH_CODE, 1) = '5' THEN 'MIN'
         WHEN LEFT(BRANCH_CODE, 1) = '7' OR
              LEFT(BRANCH_CODE, 1) = '8' THEN 'SA' END AS REGION
FROM yourTable;
```

This second version is fairly ugly IMHO, and I would probably stick with the first version, which just repeats the `SA` predicate in two places.

Comment: your second solution works for me. Thank you so much :) Sorry cant upvote your answer. Need 15 repu

Comment: @JonathanEsparas But you can accept this as answer right? Below the vote button you can see a tick button.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues when trying to apply multiple condition statements in "CASE" statement.

I solved it by moving the test after the "WHEN" statement as following :

```
SELECT (CASE 
    WHEN LEFT(BRANCH_CODE, 1) = '1' THEN 'NL'
    WHEN LEFT(BRANCH_CODE, 1) = '2' THEN 'MM'
    WHEN LEFT(BRANCH_CODE, 1) = '3' THEN 'SL'
    WHEN LEFT(BRANCH_CODE, 1) = '4' THEN 'VIS'
    WHEN LEFT(BRANCH_CODE, 1) = '5' THEN 'MIN'
    WHEN LEFT(BRANCH_CODE, 1)  IN ('7' OR '8') THEN 'SA'
 END)  `REGION`,
```

Comment: Will try this one